# php pdo update query with variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I hope someone can point out where I am going wrong with this update, I have tried various ways but just can't seem to get it to work, probably a simple mistake but I just can't seem to find it.

```
function set_live($row_id, $mobile_number)
{
    global $conn;
    $live = 1;

    $sql = "
     UPDATE 
      connections 
     SET 
      live = :live, 
      voice_number = :mobile_number 
     WHERE 
      id = :row_id";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':mobile_number', $mobile_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':row_id', $row_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':live', $live, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "Record edited successfully";
    $conn=null;
}
```

`$conn` is the PDO connection which works with SELECT's etc
All variables are numbers and all echo OK so are in the function
I can run the query with the actual values in phpmyadmin and it works OK

Comment: How you call `set_live` function??

Comment: Why are you using a `global` variable? Why don't you pass it to that method, or, better, render it a member of the class (if this is a class, of course) if you use to manipulate db? At a first glance it seems to be ok (if `$conn` is what you claim it to be; have you tried to dump `$row_id` and `$mobile_number`? Have you tried to dump `$conn` also?

Comment: You should add error handling / have PDO throw exceptions. Chances are you don't have a database connection if you set it to `null` every time you use it...

Comment: Thanks @DonCallisto it was partly to do with $conn being nulled in an earlier select function on the page, lesson learned - don't null variables unless you need to!

Comment: @ruraldev if you want to learn  a lesson ... don't ever use global variable. ever. period. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this line

```
$stmt->bindParam(':mobile_number', $mobile_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

with this

```
$stmt->bindParam(':mobile_number', $mobile_number, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Because the phone number length is more than integer.

Comment: in my case I also had made the $conn variable null earlier in the same page!

Answer (score -1):

Why not try using an Array? That approach may well do the Trick for you:

```
    <?php
        function set_live($row_id, $mobile_number){
            global $conn;
            $live = 1;
            $sql    = "UPDATE connections SET live=:live, voice_number=:mobile_number WHERE id=:row_id";
            $stmt   = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $params = array(
                "live"          =>$live,
                "mobile_number" =>$mobile_number,
                "row_id"        =>$row_id,
            );

            $stmt->execute($params);
            echo "Record edited successfully";
            $conn=null;
        }
```

Comment: Why would this work better than binding the individual values? Both are perfectly valid.

Comment: @jeroen  Where was it said that this would **work better than....** in the above post? Here is the only Sentence in the above post: **Why not** ***TRY using an Array?*** **That approach may well do the Trick for you:** ***Where is any comparison with better or worse in the above Statement?***

Comment: @jeroen Again, read between the Lines: **...MAY** **well do the Trick for you...** ***Did you notice the word*** **MAY**? That implies: ***Probability... Possibility***. Did I spell that right?

Comment: You can also suggest to change the variable names but that would not magically make it work. As you have posted this as an answer, me asking why this would solve the problem seems perfectly valid. Because I don't see any reason it would as both approaches do the same thing.

Comment: @jeroen     I will now vote you up for your sagacity ;-)